# AMPLab Shark on Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark, shark-sql

As per documentation,

"Apache Spark is a fast and general engine for large-scale data processing."

"Shark is an open source distributed SQL query engine for Hadoop data."

And Shark uses Spark as a dependency.

My question is, Is Spark just parses HiveQL into Spark jobs or does anything great if we use Shark for fast response on analytical queries ?

Comment: so..... what is your question? it's not clearly stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Shark uses the same idea as Hive but translates HiveQL into Spark jobs instead of MapReduce jobs. Please, read pages 13-14 of [this](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/reynold-xin-ampcamp-2012-08-21-Shark.pdf) document for architectural differences between these two.